# Как убрать box-shadow у изображения внутри блока?

Tags: css, scss, box-shadow

Необходимо применить box-shadow к hover блока, но почему-то он применяется не только к блоку, но и к его содержанию (картинке). Тень должна быть только при наведении на блок, но появляется эта внутренняя тень, не пойму как убрать.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/strlvgr/yrdfbv30/)

```
<div class="partners _container">
    <h1>НАШИ ПАРТНЁРЫ</h1>
    <div class="partners__links">
      <a href="#" class="partners__link">
        <div class="partners__img">
          <img src="/img/Frame 1790.png" alt="Henkel" />
        </div>
      </a>
```

```
/* Обнуление */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul,
ol,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
._container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*-------HEADER-------*/
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);

  &__container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 80px;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &__search {
    width: 763px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      width: 344px;
    }

    input#search-bar {
      margin: 0 15px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 0 39px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border: 1px solid #ebebf1;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-decoration: #bbc4d6;
      &:focus {
        transition: 0.35s ease;
        &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
          transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
          opacity: 0;
        }
        &::-moz-placeholder {
          transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
          opacity: 0;
        }
        &:-ms-placeholder {
          transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
    }
    .search-icon {
      position: relative;
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
      left: -714px;
    }
  }
  &__profile {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 5.8;
    color: #768298;
    border-left: 1px solid #ebebf1;
    a {
      color: inherit;
    }
    h2 {
      padding-left: 19px;
    }

    .profile-photo {
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}
/*-----MAIN-----*/
.partners {
  h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 46px;
  }

  &__links {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;

    :hover {
      box-shadow: -3px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 0px 10px rgba(164, 164, 164, 0.03);
    }
  }
  &__img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  &__link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 270px;
    height: 120px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #ebebf1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;

    a img {
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Перенести правило из partner__links в partner__lin**k**.

И добавить **&** к :hover

```
    &__link {

    &:hover {
      box-shadow: -3px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 0px 10px rgba(164, 164, 164, 0.03);
    }
  }
```